# Error when importing photos from iCloud to Photos on macOS: "The operation couldn't be completed. (PHAssetExportRequestErrorDomain error 2.)"

Tags: icloud, photos

When I try to [download copies of photos and videos](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209454) in Shared Albums to my own library on my Mac:

1. Open Photos, then select a Shared Album from the left-hand menu.
2. Select the photos or videos. (in my case, I selected 4.900 pictures)
3. Control-click > Import.

It takes a while, the progress bar (in form of a disk next to the zoom slider) progresses normally, but when it completes, an error message is displayed and no image is imported in my library:

> The operation couldn't be completed. (PHAssetExportRequestErrorDomain error 2.)

Version information:

- Photos Version 5.0 (151.19.150)
- macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Answer (score 3):

**Diagnosis**

By trying to import small groups of photos and videos, I found out that there is one video in the middle of my shared album that doesn't display a proper preview, and it can't be imported to my library. Probably this video is corrupted somehow in iCloud. All other photos and videos can be imported properly.

**Work around**

Importing all photos and videos before this corrupted video works, and importing all photos and videos after this corrupted video works as well.

Comment: Nice bug find. I suggest sending Apple some feedback:  https://www.apple.com/feedback/